# AWS CodeBuild docker build works but not docker compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

This is my buildspec.yml file

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
        - docker build
        - docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up
```

docker build command seems to work but not the command below, any ideas?

Comment: Code build provides reach logs. Have you inspected them?